# Doc2vec maximum similarity score of a document to a subset of documents

Tags: python, pandas, similarity, doc2vec

I am new to doc2vec. I have a dataframe with two columns: one is the id (`patent_number`), the other is a cleaned and tokenized text (`clean_description`).
For each id, I need to generate in a 3rd column (`max_similarity`) the maximum value of the similarity of the `clean_description` to a subset of `clean_description` belonging to ids in a list named `patents_snow_banch`, which identifies a sub-dataframe.
Here is an extract of the 7528 observations in the dataframe:

```
   clean_description                                         patent_number
0  ['detailed', 'description', 'preferred', 'embodied']          3930647
1  ['referring', 'first', 'fig', 'ski', 'comprise']              3930658
2  ['description', 'preferred', 'embodiments', 'solution']       3930659
...
```

My current approach is to generate a 7528X7528 similarity matrix and extract the maximum value for each `patent_number` from the subset identified by `patents_snow_banch`, but I am totally open to other approaches

I have used doc2vec to measure how similar each `clean_description` is to each of the other `clean_descriptions` in the dataframe and generate a 7528X7528 similarity matrix.

```
sample = df[['clean_description', 'patent_number']]
class MyDataframeCorpus(object):
    def __init__(self, source_df, text_col, tag_col):
        self.source_df = source_df
        self.text_col = text_col
        self.tag_col = tag_col

    def __iter__(self):
        for i, row in self.source_df.iterrows():
            yield TaggedDocument(words=simple_preprocess(row[self.text_col]), 
                                 tags=[row[self.tag_col]])

corpus_for_doc2vec = MyDataframeCorpus(sample , 'clean_description', 'patent_number')

model = Doc2Vec(vector_size=100, window=20, min_count=5, workers=11,alpha=0.025, epochs=20)
model.build_vocab(corpus_for_doc2vec)
model.train(corpus_for_doc2vec,total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)

similarity_matrix = []
index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(matutils.Dense2Corpus(model.wv.vectors.T))

for sims in index:
    similarity_matrix.append(sims)
similarity_array = np.array(similarity_matrix)
```

The training of the model seems to work fine (to my knowledge), but the outcome matrix (`similarity_array`) is 16321X16321 instead o 7528X7528.

Assuming that this problem is solvable and I can get a proper 7528X7528 matrix, I then need to find, for each observation, the maximum similarity score to the subset of ids in the matrix identified in a list named `patents_snow_banch`

Any ideas on how it can be done?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not using the `SimilarityMatrix`, nor explicitly trying to calculate all pairwise similarities, at all. Instead, just use the `gensim` `.most_similar()` method to request the single most-similar item to each of your items-of-interest.

For example, to get the single most-similar item to each of the items in the training-set, in a list in the same order they appeared in the training-set:

```py
most_similars = [model.docvecs.most_similar(doc.tags[0], topn=1) 
                 for doc in corpus_for_doc2vec]
```

This will actually store both the similar document's tag, and its similarity score - you could just save `model.docvecs.most_similar(doc.tags[0], topn=1)[0]` if you only want the tag.

(Though momentarily, inside the `.most_similar()`, all pairwise similarities will be calculated & sorted for a single target, you won't then be retaining all those less-than-best similarities in a large matrix.)

You could alternatively store results in a dict, if you instead wanted to look up top hits by `patent_number` key rather than ordinal position:

```py
most_similars_by_key = {}
for doc in corpus_for_doc2vec:
    most_similars_by_key[doc.tags[0]] = model.docvecs.most_similar(doc.tags[0], topn=1)
```

Comment: thanks, this is surely a step ahead (and it simplifies a lot). However, I am not quite there yet. In my understanding most_similar() identifies the most similar patent considering the entire trained model, I instead need to extract the most similar to a subset of the trained model. I have partly coped with that using most_similar_to_given(), but this returns only the most similar tag and not the similarity score, which I instead need. Do you know a way to extract also the similarity score?

Comment: I think I have sorted it. iI have used most_similar_to_given and than computed the dyadic similarity using the association of tags extracted.